# How to quote JSON in expect?

Tags: json, tcl, expect, double-quotes, curly-braces

I have written, the following Expect script, which works.

I would like to have only one send line and one receive line.

(If I add the `\n` inside the curly-brackets it gets sent literally, when 0x10 needs to be sent.)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# N.B. The outer set of curly brackets are quotes in TCL/expect.
# The JSON received by the server only has a *single* set of outer curly
# brackets.
# The \n is sent on a separate line as the curly quote sends a literal \n,
# rather than a 0x10.  (Double quotes *do* send a 0x10 for \n, but then I
# would have to escape every double quote inside the JSON.)

set timeout 30
spawn nc localhost 2222
send {{"method":"GET", "path":["ping"]}}
send "\n"
expect {{"code": 204}}
expect "\n"
```

How can I send and expect single lines of JSON more readably in Expect?

How can I avoid the `send`ing and `expect`ing of `\n`s on their own lines?

Comment: Exchanging JSON over a channel controlled by Expect seems like a very strange thing to be doing. (Have you considered generating the JSON rather than using a literal?)

Comment: @DonalFellows I'm (ab)using expect to *test* a JSON server...  Expect is just a mock for the client.

Comment: Even so, I'd still build the object string for real in a variable and then do `send "$json\n"` or something like that to move it out.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
append json {{"method":"GET", "path":["ping"]}} \n
send $json
```

If you have a recent (8.6.2 or later) version of Tcl, you should be able to use

```
send [string cat {{"method":"GET", "path":["ping"]}} \n]
```